# java.lang.noclassdeffounderror for JComponent mock class

Tags: java

I'm getting a java.lang.noclassdeffounderror when trying to create a mock class for Component using EasyMock.

```
private Component mockComponent;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
@Before 
public void setUp() 
{ 
   mockComponent = EasyMock.createMock(Component.class); 
}
```

Comment: have you included the necessary jars on the classpath?

Comment: Which jars re you refereing to?
I've included the EasyMock-3.0.jar in the ext folder C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\lib\ext. 
Also, to be double sure have now included the path of this jar as well in the classpath but still the same problem.
Are there any other jars I need to include?

Comment: Also, other EasyMock.createMock statements are working fine.

Comment: Maybe you could post the stacktrace. It is hard to guess from the info you provide.

Comment: Hi, 

Here is the full stack trace:

Hi Here is the full trace:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/Type
 at net.sf.cglib.core.TypeUtils.parseType(TypeUtils.java:180)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.<clinit>(KeyFactory.java:66)
 at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)

Comment: at org.easymock.internal.ClassExtensionHelper.getControl(ClassExtensionHelper.java:57)
 at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControl(EasyMock.java:2068)
 at org.easymock.EasyMock.replay(EasyMock.java:1970)
 at net.TestMaxLength.setUp(TestMaxLength.java:98)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke

Comment: (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters

Comment: (MethodRoadie.java:87)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run
(MethodRoadie.java:42)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods

(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run

Comment: (JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run

(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HI,

Managed to find out that it is not the Component class that is the problem but instead i needed asm (http://forge.ow2.org/projects/asm)

Thanks,
Parag

Answer (score 4):

EasyMock requires cglib and objenesis as libraries.

If you choose the non-dependent jar of cglib (e.g., cglib-nodep-2.2.jar), the problem is resolved, as it seems to include asm.